# Restore Windows folder backup on another server

Tags: backup, windows-backup

I have a task to copy one folder with ~ 1 million files from one server to another daily.
Well I am stuck with playing robocopy and tar utility. It takes days to do it which is not acceptable in my case. I am doing nightly windows server backup of that source folder to another folder. My question: Could I restore this backup on my 'destination' server? It should be done automatically: either using Windows Backup/Restore procedure or wbadmin. Is it doable? Thanks

Comment: Do all million files change daily? If not, consider revising your process to copy only the changed files. Also, more information about the environment would be useful: What sort of link exists between the two? What operating systems are the two computers using? The more you can tell us, the more likely it is that you can get useful advice.

Comment: well .. not all files change daily. Only some of it ... but I'm looking for *simple* solution. I mean I don't want to 'invest' much in determine only 'new' files. It would be easier to copy all. Anyway here is my environment: Source server, Destination server and server where I'm gong to run  the script or use any utility. All 3 servers are Windows 2012 R2. The folder I''m going to copy is on 'Source server' and consists of number of subfolders and etc.I already doing daily Windows folder Backup and keep it on some remote server. I'd like instead of copy/paste .. better 'restore' that backup.

Comment: What sort of network are you on (what speed/bandpass are the links between them)? I should note that `ROBOCOPY` does have switches to allow copying only files that have been changed since the last time they were copied ('archive bit'), and to reset the archive bit when they are copied; this would seem to be potentially helpful. See https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html for more information. Don't get fixated on a particular concept of a solution; look at all the possibilities.

Comment: Well I realized that the problem in my case was 'network latency'. I mean either using 'robocopy' or tar it took days and not hours. Hence I changed the approach and tar the folder on the source server, then copy it to destination server. After that I open the tar on destination server. In this case it's still long process and takes a few hours but it could be handled.
The only thing left is to try Restore folder backup that I keep on some server and Restore it on my destination server. Maybe this will be faster or more straightforward ..